# Drupal 7:Pathauto patterns from menu structure hierarchy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pathauto

I'm trying to create a Pathauto pattern which looks like "Drupal root/parent_menu_item_name/node_title" where "node_title" is a child of "parent_menu_item_name" in the menu hierarchy.

I've tried many different variations, and nothing works. I've tried the suggestions in [Menu path in Pathauto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683610/drupal-7-menu-path-in-pathauto), and none of them works at all. It just ends up outputting the node-title, with nothing before it.

I've got the latest versions of the Token and Pathauto modules installed.

Comment: Write your own token. For the same issue we wrote a token that gets all the parent paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this question has been answered by Kenan:

[Kenan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9592765/437312)

```
[node:menu-link:parent:url:path]/[node:title]
```

It works for me, so I'm very happy!

Answer (score 2):

The token combination  `[node:menu-link:parent:url:alias]/[node:menu-link]` shall work with the following modules :

- token : 7.x-1.0-beta3
- pathauto: 7.x-1.0-rc2

The token patterns seem to vary depending on the version of the token module.

Comment: 8 months later, but neither these versions nor the most recent ones fix this problem.  Also, [node:menu-link:parent:url:alias] is always invalid for me (not showing up in the list of valid tokens).  Are you sure these are the only two required modules?

Answer (score 2):

This token uses the menu titles of each parent item to build a url:

```
[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:title]
```

So if you have nested content titled: The Future -> Doc Brown -> Flux Capacitor

The above token will print out:

/the-future/doc-brown/flux-capacitor

Answer (score 2):

This combination works perfectly for me

```
[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:menu-link:title]
```

with the latest token (7.x-1.5) and pathauto (7.x-1.2).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (for book type nodes): [node:menu-link:parent:title]/[node:title]

Found on: http://www.metachunk.com/blog/drupal-7-path-auto-menu-pattern